# getting accuracy and loss of NAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

i am implementing capsule neural network with data-frame of [200* 4098]. nut after 1 epoch i am getting accuracy and loss NAN

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,roc_curve,roc_auc_score,f1_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def squash(s, axis=-1, epsilon=1e-7, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name, default_name="squash"):
        squared_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(s), axis=axis,
                                     keep_dims=True)
        safe_norm = tf.sqrt(squared_norm + epsilon)
        squash_factor = squared_norm / (1. + squared_norm)
        unit_vector = s / safe_norm
        return squash_factor * unit_vector

def condition(input, counter):
    return tf.less(counter, 100)

def loop_body(input, counter):
    output = tf.add(input, tf.square(counter))
    return output, tf.add(counter, 1)

def safe_norm(s, axis=-1, epsilon=1e-7, keep_dims=False, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name, default_name="safe_norm"):
        squared_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(s), axis=axis,
                                     keep_dims=keep_dims)
        return tf.sqrt(squared_norm + epsilon)


df=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/subject3.csv')


tf.reset_default_graph()
np.random.seed(42)
tf.set_random_seed(42)
X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 4097, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name="X")

conv1_params = {
    "filters": 32,
    "kernel_size": 4,
    "strides": 2,
    "padding": "valid",
    "activation": tf.nn.relu,
}

conv2_params = {
    "filters": 32,#caps1_n_maps * caps1_n_dims, # 256 convolutional filters
    "kernel_size": 4,
    "strides": 3,
    "padding": "valid",
    "activation": tf.nn.relu
}

conv1 = tf.layers.conv1d(X, name="conv1", **conv1_params)
conv2 = tf.layers.conv1d(conv1, name="conv2", **conv2_params) 
print("conv layer shape ",conv1.shape, conv2.shape)

caps1_n_maps = 16
caps1_n_caps = caps1_n_maps * 8   # 1152 primary capsules
caps1_n_dims = 4

caps1_raw = tf.reshape(conv2,[-1, caps1_n_caps, caps1_n_dims],
                       name="caps1_raw")
print(caps1_raw.shape)
print(caps1_raw.get_shape().as_list()[0])

caps1_output = squash(caps1_raw, name="caps1_output")
print("output of Caps1 ",caps1_output) 



caps2_n_caps = 2
caps2_n_dims = 16

init_sigma = 0.1

W_init = tf.random_normal(
    shape=(1, caps1_n_caps, caps2_n_caps, caps2_n_dims, caps1_n_dims),
    stddev=init_sigma, dtype=tf.float32, name="W_init")

W = tf.Variable(W_init, name="W")
batch_size = tf.shape(X)[0]
W_tiled = tf.tile(W, [batch_size, 1, 1, 1, 1], name="W_tiled")
caps1_output_expanded = tf.expand_dims(caps1_output, -1,
                                       name="caps1_output_expanded")
caps1_output_tile = tf.expand_dims(caps1_output_expanded, 2,
                                   name="caps1_output_tile")
caps1_output_tiled = tf.tile(caps1_output_tile, [1, 1, caps2_n_caps, 1, 1],
                             name="caps1_output_tiled")

caps2_predicted = tf.matmul(W_tiled, caps1_output_tiled,
                            name="caps2_predicted")
print(W_tiled)
print(caps1_output_tiled)
print(caps2_predicted)





raw_weights = tf.zeros([batch_size, caps1_n_caps, caps2_n_caps, 1, 1],
                       dtype=np.float32, name="raw_weights")
routing_weights = tf.nn.softmax(raw_weights, dim=2, name="routing_weights")
weighted_predictions = tf.multiply(routing_weights, caps2_predicted,
                                   name="weighted_predictions")
weighted_sum = tf.reduce_sum(weighted_predictions, axis=1, keep_dims=True,
                             name="weighted_sum")
caps2_output_round_1 = squash(weighted_sum, axis=-2,
                              name="caps2_output_round_1")
caps2_output_round_1_tiled = tf.tile(
    caps2_output_round_1, [1, caps1_n_caps, 1, 1, 1],
    name="caps2_output_round_1_tiled")
agreement = tf.matmul(caps2_predicted, caps2_output_round_1_tiled,
                      transpose_a=True, name="agreement")

raw_weights_round_2 = tf.add(raw_weights, agreement,
                             name="raw_weights_round_2")





routing_weights_round_2 = tf.nn.softmax(raw_weights_round_2,
                                        dim=2,
                                        name="routing_weights_round_2")
weighted_predictions_round_2 = tf.multiply(routing_weights_round_2,
                                           caps2_predicted,
                                           name="weighted_predictions_round_2")
weighted_sum_round_2 = tf.reduce_sum(weighted_predictions_round_2,
                                     axis=1, keep_dims=True,
                                     name="weighted_sum_round_2")
caps2_output_round_2 = squash(weighted_sum_round_2,
                              axis=-2,
                              name="caps2_output_round_2")
caps2_output = caps2_output_round_2
print(caps2_output)



y_proba = safe_norm(caps2_output, axis=-2, name="y_proba")
y_proba_argmax = tf.argmax(y_proba, axis=2, name="y_proba")
y_pred = tf.squeeze(y_proba_argmax, axis=[1,2], name="y_pred")
y_pred
y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int64, name="y")
m_plus = 0.9
m_minus = 0.1
lambda_ = 0.5
T = tf.one_hot(y, depth=caps2_n_caps, name="T")
with tf.Session():
    print(T.eval(feed_dict={y: np.array([0, 1])}))




caps2_output_norm = safe_norm(caps2_output, axis=-2, keep_dims=True,
                              name="caps2_output_norm")



present_error_raw = tf.square(tf.maximum(0., m_plus - caps2_output_norm),
                              name="present_error_raw")
present_error = tf.reshape(present_error_raw, shape=(-1, 2),
                           name="present_error")
absent_error_raw = tf.square(tf.maximum(0., caps2_output_norm - m_minus),
                             name="absent_error_raw")
absent_error = tf.reshape(absent_error_raw, shape=(-1, 2),
                          name="absent_error")
L = tf.add(T * present_error, lambda_ * (1.0 - T) * absent_error,
           name="L")
margin_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(L, axis=1), name="margin_loss")
mask_with_labels = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=(),
                                               name="mask_with_labels")



reconstruction_targets = tf.cond(mask_with_labels, # condition
                                 lambda: y,        # if True
                                 lambda: y_pred,   # if False
                                 name="reconstruction_targets")
reconstruction_mask = tf.one_hot(reconstruction_targets,
                                 depth=caps2_n_caps,
                                 name="reconstruction_mask")
reconstruction_mask_reshaped = tf.reshape(
    reconstruction_mask, [-1, 1, caps2_n_caps, 1, 1],
    name="reconstruction_mask_reshaped")



caps2_output_masked = tf.multiply(
    caps2_output, reconstruction_mask_reshaped,
    name="caps2_output_masked")
decoder_input = tf.reshape(caps2_output_masked,
                           [-1, caps2_n_caps * caps2_n_dims],
                           name="decoder_input")
n_hidden1 = 512
n_hidden2 = 1024
n_output = 4097 * 1
with tf.name_scope("decoder"):
    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(decoder_input, n_hidden1,
                              activation=tf.nn.relu,
                              name="hidden1")
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_hidden2,
                              activation=tf.nn.relu,
                              name="hidden2")
    decoder_output = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, n_output,
                                     activation=tf.nn.sigmoid,
                                     name="decoder_output")

X_flat = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_output], name="X_flat")
squared_difference = tf.square(X_flat - decoder_output,
                               name="squared_difference")
reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference,
                                    name="reconstruction_loss")


alpha = 0.0005

loss = tf.add(margin_loss, alpha * reconstruction_loss, name="loss")
print(loss)
correct = tf.equal(y, y_pred, name="correct")
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32), name="accuracy")
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name="training_op")
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
y_res=df[df.columns[-1]].values
x=df[df.columns[0:-1]].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y_res,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
len(x_train),len(y_train),len(x_test),len(y_train)

restore_checkpoint = True

n_iterations_per_epoch = len(x_train)// batch_size
n_iterations_validation = len(x_test) // batch_size
best_loss_val = np.infty


start1=0
start2=0
start=0
batch_size = 1
n_epochs = 10
checkpoint_path = "./my_capsule_network"
with tf.Session() as sess:
    if restore_checkpoint and tf.train.checkpoint_exists(checkpoint_path):
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
    else:
        init.run()

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for iteration in range(1, n_iterations_per_epoch + 1):
             X_batch=x_train[start1:start1+batch_size]
             y_batch=y_train[start1:start1+batch_size]

             start1+=batch_size
             #Run the training operation and measure the loss:
             _,loss_train = sess.run(
                [training_op, loss],
                feed_dict={X: X_batch.reshape([-1, 4097,1]),
                           y: y_batch,
                           mask_with_labels: True})
             print("\rIteration: {}/{} ({:.1f}%)  Loss: {:.5f}".format(
                      iteration, n_iterations_per_epoch,
                      iteration * 100 / n_iterations_per_epoch,
                      loss_train),
                  end="")

        # At the end of each epoch,
        # measure the validation loss and accuracy:
        loss_vals = []
        acc_vals = []
        for iteration in range(1, n_iterations_validation + 1):
            X_batch=x_test[start2:start2+batch_size]
            y_batch=y_test[start2:start2+batch_size]
            start2+=batch_size
            loss_val, acc_val = sess.run(
                    [loss, accuracy],
                    feed_dict={X: X_batch.reshape([-1, 4097,1]),
                               y: y_batch})
            loss_vals.append(loss_val)
            acc_vals.append(acc_val)
            print("\rEvaluating the model: {}/{} ({:.1f}%)".format(
                      iteration, n_iterations_validation,
                      iteration * 100 / n_iterations_validation),
                  end=" " * 10)
        loss_val = np.mean(loss_vals)
        start+=batch_size
        acc_val = np.mean(acc_vals)
        print("\rEpoch: {}  Val accuracy: {:.4f}%  Loss: {:.6f}{}".format(
            epoch + 1, acc_val * 100, loss_val,
            " (improved)" if loss_val < best_loss_val else ""))

        # And save the model if it improved:
        if loss_val < best_loss_val:
            save_path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path)
            best_loss_val = loss_val
```

and i am getting the output AS:

```
Epoch: 1  Val accuracy: 53.3333%  Loss: 0.319774 (improved)

Epoch: 2  Val accuracy: nan%  Loss: nan

Epoch: 3  Val accuracy: nan%  Loss: nan

Epoch: 4  Val accuracy: nan%  Loss: nan

Epoch: 5  Val accuracy: nan%  Loss: nan

Epoch: 6  Val accuracy: nan%  Loss: nan

Epoch: 7  Val accuracy: nan%  Loss: nan

Epoch: 8  Val accuracy: nan%  Loss: nan

Epoch: 9  Val accuracy: nan%  Loss: nan

Epoch: 10  Val accuracy: nan%  Loss: nan
```

i opted batch size to be 1 because even after trying some batch sizes , i didnt get the result

Comment: Do you normalize your input? 90% of the times, getting `NaN` results is a symptom of that...

Comment: yes. i did    but still getting the NAN

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with normalization or dataset.

You should just reset `start1` and `start2` variables to zero at the beginning of each epochs:

```
...
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    start1 = 0
    start2 = 0
    for iteration in range(1, n_iterations_per_epoch + 1):
    ...
```